# A Mayer-Vietoris question

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-groups

> Let $A = C \times T^{n - 1}$ and $B = D \times T^{n - 1}$, where $C$ and $D$ are two overlapping arcs of one of the $S^1$'s satisfying that $S^1 = C \cup D$ and $T^n = S^1 \times \cdots \times S^1$. Now consider the Mayer-Vietoris sequence
>
> $$ \cdots \to H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B)\to H_n(T^n) \to H_{n - 1}(A \cap B) \to H_{n - 1}(A) \oplus H_{n - 1}(B) \to \cdots$$
>
> Assume that $H_{n - 1}(A) = H_{n - 1}(B) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. It is not hard to see that $A \cap B \simeq T^{n - 1} \sqcup T^{n - 1}$, which implies that $\varphi_* \colon H_{n - 1}(A \cap B) \to H_{n - 1}(A) \oplus H_{n - 1}(B)$ is a homomorphism between two groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

My question

> Is $\ker \varphi_{*} \cong H_{n - 1}(A)$?

I believe the answer is yes because, as far as I understand, $\varphi\colon C_{n - 1}(A \cap B) \to C_{n - 1}(A) \oplus C_{n - 1}(B)$ sends $x$ to $(x, -x)$, which means that $\ker \varphi_*$ are... the cycles in $C_{n - 1}(A)$?

Comment: How is $A\cap B=T^{n-1}\sqcup T^{n-1}$, is $C\cap D$ *equal* to a two-point set? Why do you call a homomorphism $G\to H$ with $G$ and $H$ isomorphic and endomorphism? You shouldn't forget about the isomorphisms involved.

Comment: @Christoph yes, $C \cap D$ is a two-point set, well two non-intersecting arcs of $S^1$. I called it an endomorphism because it is not clear to me that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: So $C\cap D$ is only homotopy equivalent to two points and hence $A\cap B\simeq T^{n-1}\sqcup T^{-1}$ is also *only a homotopy equivalence, not an equality*. I didn't claim $\varphi_*$ is an isomorphism, it is a homomorphism between two isomorphic groups (both are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$), but that is different from an endomorphism, which is a homomorphism from a group *to itself*!

Comment: @Christoph yes to both of your remarks; and fixed.